# Subset of a first category set (Baire's category)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, baire-category

I'm trying to prove that any subset of a first category set is of first category.

I would like to know if my proof is correct and if there are easier way to prove it. Any check is thankfully appreciated.

**Here my reasoning**:
Let $A$ be a first category set, and $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of *nowhere dense* sets such that their (countable) union generates $A$.
If $B$ is a subset of $A$, then exist a subsequence $\{A_{n_j}\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ and a set $A_{\overline{n}}$ such that:
$$
 \bigcup_{j} A_{n_j} \subseteq B \subseteq \bigcup_{j} A_{n_j} \cup A_{\overline{n}}
$$
Let $E =B \setminus \bigcup_{j} A_{n_j}$. We therefore get $\, E \subseteq A_{\overline{n}} \,$, so that $E\,$ is nowhere dense as $A_{\overline{n}}$ is.
We can finally write:
$$
B = \bigcup_{j} A_{n_j} \cup E
$$
Where $E$ and every $A_{n_j}$ are nowhere dense.

Comment: Simpler (after $B$ and $A_n$ are defined) --- Since each subset of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense, the following shows that $B$ can be expressed as a countable union of nowhere dense sets: $B \; = \; B\cap A \; = \; B \; \cap \; \left[ \bigcup_{n\in\omega}A_n \right] \; = \; \bigcup_{n\in\omega} (B\cap A_n),$ where the last equality is because intersection distributes over union.

Comment: If $A$ is nowhere dense and $B \subseteq A$, then $\overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A}$ and so $\operatorname{int}(\overline{B}) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(\overline{A}) = \emptyset$ so $B$ is nowhere dense too. So a subset of a union of nowhere dense subsets is itself a union of nowhere dense subsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, an easier proof is consider the family $\{A_n\cap B\}_{n\in\omega}$. The sets $A_n\cap B$ are closed, (without lost of generality we can assume that each $A_n$ is closed) with empty interior (in the subespace topology) and $B=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}B\cap A_n$.

Comment: +1, mainly because I stole what you essentially wrote for my comment above. Incidentally, I would avoid saying anything about sets being closed and having empty interior, unless the fact that *nowhere dense* is a hereditary property isn't available, in which case this would best be done in a preliminary lemma (besides, that fact is itself of some interest).